# How to implement communication between Java client application (Android) and PHP server application?

Tags: java, php, android, client-server

I have a simple Java client application (Android app). I have to write a PHP server application which receives a request from the Java client application to write some data to a MySQL database or read some data from the MySQL database. It should respond with a status message (Write failed/success) or the data requested respectively.

How would I get the Java client send a request and receive the reply from the PHP program and how would the PHP program receive the request and send the reply? I have googled about SOAP and REST architectures, but looking for a simple tutorial which will allow me to implement this simple program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

With basic Java SE API you can use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to fire a HTTP request. A basic example of firing a `GET` request can be found in [Sun tutorial on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html). A `POST` request isn't much different, you instead just need to set [`URLConnection#setDoOutput()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29) to `true` and write the query string to [`URLConnection#getOutputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream%28%29) instead of in URL.

Note that it's "lazily executed", the request will only be fired if you actually obtain the response stream by [`URLConnection#getInputStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29), even though you don't need it.

If you want less verbose code and/or more control over the request, then I can recommend to use [Apache Commons HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/).

The PHP program in turn can just be written the usual way. Get request parameters by `$_GET`, `$_POST` and so on and `echo` the response. Nothing special needs to be done here. You may however consider to use an more easy parseable response format, such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Let us suppose that we have sent a HTTP request to the PHP program which receives the $_GET/$_POST parameters, does some processing and wants to echo back a string "Processing successful". Do I just simply do echo $string and the Java program will receive it in URLConnection's InputStream ?

Comment: On running the script provided in the tutorial I am encountering the error as given on the page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment but I am not able to guess the reason for the same.

Comment: One more solution of above was provided here at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2008/11/android-testing-on-android-platform.html but again this didn't help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You should build a simple JSON or XML based REST web service with PHP.

Then with the Android SDK, you can use the [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) module to connect to your web service. The SDK also provide a [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) and [XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) module to parse the result.