# ShouldNotReachhere classFileParser ANDROID

Tags: android, fatal-error

Any idea how to fix this issue?  I'm using Eclipse and it seems to occur even when I create a new android project. :(

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3174), pid=3944, tid=3256
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
```

Comment: Does it occur when creating Java projects too?

Answer (score 36):

Use "Run configurations" and make sure you select the Android application.

Comment: Worked for me. I caused this error by attempting to execute a file in an android file as a JAVA application.

Comment: I had imported a project and it for some reason defaulted to run as a javabean, and I was getting this error; had to edit run config settings and reset to android app...

Comment: Cheers, it turns out I was launching a different project to the one I had selected.

Comment: Right on. Run config had switched from Android App to Java App. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this by

- Quit eclipse
- Delete the **bin** and **gen** directories in your project
- Start eclipse
- Rebuild your project

Comment: Thx, worked for me. On top of reconfiguring the "Run As.. Android application" i/o "Junit appl. Simple and efficiency. Saved a hard day of reinstalling a compliant JRE..

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting this error when running JUnit tests? If so, it seems like the fault I had but found a solution to. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment/3223929#3223929)

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this error and thought it had something to do with my JRE since the documents specifically state 1.5 or 1.6, however it seems that there is one easy step that I (and it appears others) skimmed over. You must exclude the Android Bootstrap from the run configuration. Go to "Edit Run Configurations" and select the DatabaseConfigUtil run configuration and then go to the "Classpath" tab and remove the "Android Bootstrap".

A big thanks goes to this useful thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ormlite-android/Qaw4JD2KJ1Q

EDIT: I just realized that while my problem was the same, we had different goals. In your case you were trying to run an Android Project as a Java Application, however my issue was trying to run the ORMLite generator Java Application within an Android Project and it was automatically adding the android bootstrap to the classpath. So in the case mentioned in the question simply running it as an Android project instead of a Java Application should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that error, but you can try the standard fixes: update or reinstall your JRE and the Android SDK. Might help...

Answer (score 0):

Happens for me too but seems related to projects that depend on other library projects. This happens if I hit F11 to rerun while in the library project, but not when I do that from the app. I think it just gets confused when it tries to figure out how to run a library. So the workaround is simple enough but sure wasn't obvious to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Well...I think the problem is because you are using de android enviroment to run java applications. Probably you insert java code inside android structure and it can not "read" this.

Comment: Please expand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you might had set launcher as Eclipse JUnit Launcher. if so you need to change to Android JUnit Test Launcher.

to do this

1. right click on the code window
2. run as
3. run configurations
4. at the bottom of the popup window you'll see a text which is saying "**Using Eclipse JUnit Launcher**" and a link at right of it texted as **select other**
5. click on **select other**  and change to Android JUnit Test Launcher
6. run