# Runtime error when JUnit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, jvm

I am pretty shaky with Unit testing but I have a part of my code I really need to be certain of its consistency. I am attempting to transfer data from an object to an external file using JSON so I want to make sure when I pull the data from the external file it will be the same.

I am using a Unit test to assert this equality but I am encountering a problem I am not sure how to handle. It is a runtime error and this is what the console reads.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3494), pid=5032, tid=7048
Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
An error report file with more information is saved as:
L:\fliphouseWorkspace\Luas\hs_err_pid5032.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: [Fatal error by Java runtime environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment)

Comment: @Tomasz Blachowicz is right. check if android. most of Android is getting such ERROR

Comment: Similar to [Can't run JUnit 4 test case in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172152/cant-run-junit-4-test-case-in-eclipse)

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172152/cant-run-junit-4-test-case-in-eclipse explains how to 'fix' the issue in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse to develop an Android app, here's another possible explanation: http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/17/worked-out-why/.  (Apparently, this can also occur if you try / have tried to develop Android and regular Java in the same Eclipse Workspace; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223929/139985)

If you are not, then I think that the general problem is that the JVM is falling over while trying to parse (probably load) a class file.  The most likely cause seems to be that the class file is mangled in some way.  If that's the case, then this is not a JVM bug.  The JVM may have no choice but to report this kind of problem via a crash report, because it could happen during JVM bootstrapping.

---

Here's an entry in the Java Bug Database that reports this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7032077.  Unfortunately, it has been closed as not reproducible.

Comment: If there's a mangled class file, the JVM should spew a proper exception complaining about it, not fall over in this way, so it's arguably still a bug.

Comment: @artbristol - I've covered that in the last 2 sentences of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's nothing to do with your code, that looks like a genuine JVM bug to me.  The JVM should never crash like that.  File a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I did look at the log file for further details and its pretty detailed but confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using android, because most of the people seem to be having issues with android and junit.
I found this blog entry where they discuss the particular issue in the comments section.
One of the comments mentions this particular error.
You could find some help here.
http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2008/11/android-testing-on-android-platform.html

One of the options suggested is to delete the "bin" and "gen" directory, and try again.
[ShouldNotReachhere classFileParser ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904761/shouldnotreachhere-classfileparser-android)

Comment: Umm no, it says which JVM he is using, which is not the android one.

Comment: @Tnem, ok I have to edit this once again, got to have some coffee. Looks like the JUNIT uses the JVM

Comment: Dead on I am developing an app and trying to test it. I'm pretty inexperienced in both kinds of Unit testing and was only trying to test in Java first. Thats probably a bad way of testing Android but I wasn't really testing anything to do with Android. Thanks for the reply. I think I will get a tester project going to test.