# Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3174), pid=7288, tid=7476

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming.
My requirement is to call an HTTP request via HttpClient.
Below is the code :

public class ClientWithResponseHandler {
  public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 
     System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());
     // Create a response handler
     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
     String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
     System.out.println(responseBody);

     System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

     // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, 
     // shut down the connection manager to ensure
     // immediate deallocation of all system resources
     httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();        
 }
```

}

After executing the above code as a Java Application i get the below error in the console.

---

#

## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#

## Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3174), pid=7288, tid=7476

## Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

#

## JRE version: 6.0_20-b02

## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )

## An error report file with more information is saved as:

## C:\Sandeep\eclipse\workspace\HelloWebService\hs_err_pid7288.log

#

## If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

## http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

#

---

Any idea what could be the problem

Regards
Sandeep

Comment: have tou try to delete bin and gen directories (after having closed eclipse) , and rebuild project ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2172175/611007

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment) and my answer to that:

I got the same problem, but with alot of googling I found the answer! [See this page](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2008/11/android-testing-on-android-platform.html)

Quote from the link:

---

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:2924), pid=5364, tid=6644
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere
```

1. That's because we are using Android's JUnit stub implementation. Go to Run -> Run As -> Run configurations again and in the recently created JUnit configuration Classpath's Bootstrap Entries remove Android Library
2. Then Add Library, using Advanced... button, and add JRE System Library and JUnit 3
3. Apply and Run

---

Try this, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Fredrik said, consider using [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) instead of `DefaultHttpClient` on an Android.

Answer (score 0):

i removed the run configuration and created a new one again

Answer (score 0):

Becase you use Java class, Eclipse think Project is Java not a Android. So,when you click "run", Eclipse will run as Java App.  You should chick Run as->Android Application.