# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: Internal Error ; Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

Tags: eclipse, java, fatal-error

I have no idea what went wrong as I've programmed in Java for about a year and never got this error. Compiling and running in Eclipse worked just a minute ago and now I get this error:

---

```
#A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3494), pid=4636, tid=2380

#Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

#JRE version: 6.0_25-b06

#Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode windows-x86 )

#If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

#http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x02339800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2380, stack(0x00240000,0x00290000)]

Stack: [0x00240000,0x00290000],  sp=0x0028f86c,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x13363a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12e59b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x164ce]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17cff]
V  [jvm.dll+0x26de5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27626]
V  [jvm.dll+0x279d5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27a69]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27b2c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27baa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27c8d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27f59]
V  [jvm.dll+0x6c593]
V  [jvm.dll+0x6c96c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf9c1c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1184bb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x9eba0]
C  [javaw.exe+0x1657]
C  [javaw.exe+0x1e2c]
C  [javaw.exe+0x8614]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x13677]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f02]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ed5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x02339800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2380, stack(0x00240000,0x00290000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x77370000 - 0x774f0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x752e0000 - 0x753e0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75200000 - 0x75246000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x76a30000 - 0x76ad0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76b90000 - 0x76c3c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x76c40000 - 0x76c59000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x75940000 - 0x75a30000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74ee0000 - 0x74f40000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74ed0000 - 0x74edc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x75a40000 - 0x75b40000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x75250000 - 0x752e0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x75790000 - 0x7579a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x76790000 - 0x7682d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x756d0000 - 0x75730000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75600000 - 0x756cc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74770000 - 0x747a2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x70c70000 - 0x70cbb000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x77340000 - 0x77345000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar 
java_command: elf.app.RoomInfoActivity
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse;
USERNAME=ryu_eMach_E732Z
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 2874176k(1587204k free), swap 5746452k(3983880k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_25-b06), built on Apr 14 2011 01:04:32 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Mon May 16 14:17:52 2011
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like an internal JVM error. You could submit a bug report to Sun/Oracle as suggested in the error message. Apart from that, without more details on what your code did before the error, it is impossible for anyone over here to say much.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110972/internal-error-classfileparser-cpp3174-pid-7288-tid-7476), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904761/shouldnotreachhere-classfileparser-android) for possible answers to the same issue.

Comment: When using Eclipse, trust nothing. It seems we, as Eclipse users, are expected to refresh and restart the IDE frequently, or lose countless hours hunting down red herrings like this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't run JUnit 4 test case in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172152/cant-run-junit-4-test-case-in-eclipse)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543106/fatal-error-by-java-runtime-environment?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem when running "pure java junit test" inside an android dev project.

so the solution was to do the following in Eclipse:

- Add the std JRE to "properties --> java build path --> libraries"
- While running, In the "runconfiguration --> classpath" remove Android (leaving only
  std JRE)

Comment: Thanks! Removing the Android library and keeping only the "JRE System Library" in the Bootstrap Entries of the Classpath tab of the JUnit Run Configuration in Eclipse worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

## Here is your relief for the problem :

I have a problem of running different versions of STS this morning, the application crash with the similar way as the question did.

Excerpt of my log file.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#a
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f459db082a1, pid=4577, tid=139939015632640
#
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
(20.5-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  short+0x11
```

note that exception occured at # **C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  short+0x11**

Okay then little below the line :

```
R9 =0x00007f461829e550: <offset 0xa85550> in /usr/share/java/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f4617819000
R10=0x00007f461750f7c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f4610008000
R11=0x00007f459db08290: soup_session_feature_detach+0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1 at 0x00007f459da9c000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000074404c840 is an oop
{method}
```

This line tells you where the actual bug or crash is to investigate more on this crash issue please use below links to know more , but let continue the crash investigation and how i resolved it and the novelty of this bug :)

links ARE :

[a fATAL ERROR JAVA](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501) THIS ONE IS GREAT LOTS OF USER!

[a fATAL ERROR JAVA 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm)

Okay , after that here what i found out to casue of this case and why it happens a general advise.

1. Most of the time ,check that if u have installed , updated recently on Ubunu and Windows  there are libraries  like **libsoup** in linux whihc were the casuse of my crash.
2. Check also a new Hardware problem and try to investigate the `Logfile` which `STS` or `Java` generated and also `syslog` in `linux` by

   ```
   tail - f /var/lib/messages or some other file
   ```

   Then by carfully looking at those file the one you have crash log ... you can really solve the issue as follow .

> sudo unlink /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1

or

> sudo unlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1

**Done !! Cheers!!**

Comment: Worked for me right away, will report back on dependencies if any

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem.

**Error Log:**

> EAX=0x08aef338
>   0x08aef338 is pointing to unknown location
>
> EBX=0x7c5e7000
>   0x7c5e7000:  in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1 at 0x7c558000

**Fix:**

```
unlink /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1
```

Comment: How do you relink the file after unlinking it? This seems to cause unity issues with the clock and Wi-Fi

Answer (score 1):

Just check to see what file you're actually running when you hit the run button.  I had the same issue when I wrote a "public static void main" statement in a "non-main" file of the program.  I even commented it out, but it wouldn't work. This [link](http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/16/solved-internal-error-classfileparser-cpp3161/) was very helpful for me.

Comment: thanks for that link, I came across that same entry in that blog when I did a google search (or maybe I'm remembering it wrong and I clicked on your link..)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error and solved it by using 'Run As' and choosing 'Android Application'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a corrupt class file. Rebuild.

Comment: That wasn't the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Change the workspace.

I don't know the reason but this worked for me..

Hope this helps to you as well !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after adding main method in one of my classes in an Android project. I just right click on the project and run it as an Android project and then it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. The command

```
sudo unlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1
```

was also not useful as it crashed my system network and not able to connect Wi-Fi or wired lan. Later i got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crashing).

Adding line `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` at the end of `eclipse.ini` or `org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` at the end of `/eclipse/configuration/config.ini` file solved the issue.