# SIGSEGV while running run-app on grails 2.4.3

Tags: hibernate, grails, segmentation-fault

I wrote an app on a MacOS Mavericks MacbookAir laptop. It works fine. Then I checked out the code on another laptop, a Mavericks MacbookPro (pre retina).

When I launch the grails console, it works fine. Once I try to execute `run-app`, I get the SIGSEGV.

This is what shows up on the screen:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010fff41af, pid=85762, tid=23811
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4261af]  Klass::is_subtype_of(Klass*) const+0x7
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /cores/core or core.85762
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/rsom/src/maas/hs_err_pid85762.log
#
```

When I look at the hs_err_pid log file, this is what I see

```
Stack: [0x0000000127ab1000,0x0000000127bb1000],  sp=0x0000000127bad860,  free space=1010k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4261af]  Klass::is_subtype_of(Klass*) const+0x7
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a50e5]  LinkResolver::runtime_resolve_interface_method(CallInfo&, methodHandle, KlassHandle, Handle, KlassHandle, bool, Thread*)+0x7b
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a593f]  LinkResolver::resolve_interface_call(CallInfo&, Handle, KlassHandle, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, KlassHandle, bool, bool, Thread*)+0xd1
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a5af3]  LinkResolver::resolve_invokeinterface(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x143
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a69b0]  LinkResolver::resolve_invoke(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Bytecodes::Code, Thread*)+0x3ce
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2ce675]  InterpreterRuntime::resolve_invoke(JavaThread*, Bytecodes::Code)+0x371
j  org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/validation/ValidatorFactory;Ljava/util/Set;ZLorg/hibernate/dialect/Dialect;)V+1
j  org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(Ljavax/validation/ValidatorFactory;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Properties;Lorg/hibernate/dialect/Dialect;)V+121
j  org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyRelationalConstraints(Ljavax/validation/ValidatorFactory;Lorg/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/ActivationContext;)V+106
j  org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(Lorg/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/ActivationContext;)V+88
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I had a coworker with an identical laptop do the same on his machine, and he's able to launch the app.

What could be going wrong?

Any pointers on what I how I can debug?

The source is here: https://github.com/rahulsom/maas

Comment: Have you tried running a `grails clean` on the machine for this project?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I tried that. Still the same results.

Comment: What kind of jvm have the laptops? Are the same?

Comment: @GiuseppeIaco
Same JVM. Tried 4 different JDK7s and 1 JDK8 including latest in both lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days, a colleague of mine told me to run the same on an older JVM. So I tried 7u55. And it worked on 3 other computers which failed on 7u60, 7u67 and 8u20.

Apparently there's a regression in the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

It could be hardware problem. I had similar problem while running android studio and it was due to problem in my RAM. I changed it and the problem was solved. No such problem after that.

The similar problem had happened to another guy who had asked [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm) . Finally his problem was "It was a hardware problem".

Comment: I had similar experience before, RAM issue