# error of java runtime environment

Tags: java, gate, jvm-crash

I was running a JAR file, and got this error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe8e611a009, pid=15661, tid=15690
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /home/yjiang/GATE_Developer_8.2/bin/core.15661)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/yjiang/GATE_Developer_8.2/bin/hs_err_pid15661.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Could any one know how to fix it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/791021/unable-to-open-jar-files-with-java

Comment: Add more information to your question.

Comment: This site is specifically for programming problems, not for general computer problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV, libjvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is duplicate of https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166474 unfortunatly we could not fix this as we are unable to reproduce it our end due to non availability of test case. If you have reporducer test case kindly share with us we will reopen the issue.