# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment (ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux

There's such a message, what would it mean?

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f309d0693fa, pid=3899, tid=0x00007f3058ab1700

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b198) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b198)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b198 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
 v  ~BufferBlob::jni_fast_GetLongField

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x00007f30ac885800):  JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3919, stack(0x00007f30589b1000,0x00007f3058ab2000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f30b2ae01a0, RBX=0x00007f30ac8859e0, RCX=0x00007f30b35342c0, RDX=0x0000000000000042
RSP=0x00007f3058ab06a8, RBP=0x00007f3058ab06d0, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00007f30ac8859e0
R8 =0x00000000e2c43150, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x000000000000244c, R11=0x0000000000000320
R12=0x00007f3032cd8a90, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007f305b1d27e0, R15=0x00007f30ac885800
RIP=0x00007f309d0693fa, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

Comment: Do you have JNI? If so, it probably crashed. If not, you found a bug.

Comment: See this thread for a number possible solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm