# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code while loading java .jar file

Tags: java

Facing a problem while loading a **.jar** file of **java**. Sometimes it's working fine but most of the time it's doesn't work. Getting the following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd679b57902, pid=8420, tid=8422

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.2+9) (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [libc.so.6+0x82902]
[timeout occurred during error reporting in step "printing problematic frame"] after 30 s.
Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e %P %I %h" (or dumping to /home/mostafiz/core.8420)

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Already tried with [A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV, libjvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm)
but can not get any proper reason for occurring this error. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: seems like a corrupted jar? like if it didn't upload properly/completely

Comment: Perhaps core dump file (/home/mostafiz/core.8420) will have more details.

Comment: may be not as it work for sometimes.

Comment: Looks like it wrote a core dump, you may be able to pass that on to the Openjdk or Oracle folks to take a look at.  Maybe try and open the jar file with 7zip and see if it looks ok?

Comment: If this is a public jar file, could you let us know which one it is? If it is one you have built yourself, does it use any native libraries?

Comment: @ewramner private jar file