# Safest way to exchange data between java android app and PHP script?

Tags: java, php, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement communication between Java client application (Android) and PHP server application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259438/how-to-implement-communication-between-java-client-application-android-and-php)

I'm busy with a project. My android app needs to request server info from time
to time.

The solution i came up with was to write a php script. 
But how do you let the android java app communicate with the PHP script ?

I was thinking about something with a post/get request and the php script
returning a html file with strings ?

Would love some advice, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

see this tutorial it will help you

[connection between php android using http and json](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)

Answer (score 1):

From Android, do HTTP GET/POST requests to reach the PHP script. Have the PHP script return [JSON](http://json.org) formatted data - much easier to parse and deal with than HTML.

Answer (score 1):

you can exchange array between them by JSON,most of language support JSON.
in php you can use

`json_encode();
json_decode();`

to make json array.and Java should have something same as it.
eg:

```
$array = array(
            "fname" => "Moein"
            "lname" => "Hoseini"

             );
$js = json_encode($array);
```